# Invalid login: 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, SmtpClientAuthentication is disabled for the Tenant

Tags: node.js, nodemailer, microsoft365

Invalid login: 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, SmtpClientAuthentication is disabled for the Tenant. Visit https://aka.ms/smtp_auth_disabled for more information. [BL0PR1501CA0024.namprd15.prod.outlook.com]

Answer (score 0):

It means that you have to enable the SMTP Authentication from your email account in order to allow access to the `Nodemailer`.

This is a [link to the Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/authenticated-client-smtp-submission). Are you using an external server like Godaddy?

Comment: But Microsoft account is not showing any type of setting for enable it.

Comment: I am using external server "GoDaddy", got same error, what should I do?

Comment: Im using GoDaddy as well. I turned smtp on but I am still receiving this error.